# Blackberry custombutton on touch/trackpad frozen screen

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-jde, touch-event, trackpad

I created a sort of a grid with multiple vertical and horizontal fieldmanagers. [image: photo of the final result]
The code to create the grid is:

```
public class CategoriasScreen extends MainScreen {

private int colores [] = {Color.BLUE, Color.ALICEBLUE, Color.CHOCOLATE, Color.DARKORANGE, Color.YELLOW};
private int rows;

public CategoriasScreen(){
    VerticalFieldManager row;
    CategoriaFieldManager cat;
    HorizontalFieldManager par;
    EncodedImage eImage;
    LabelField lf;

    rows = 1;
    Font font = getFont().derive(Font.PLAIN, Font.getDefault().getHeight() - 8);        
    setTitle("Categorias");
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
        row = new VerticalFieldManager(Field.FIELD_VCENTER | Manager.USE_ALL_WIDTH | Field.NON_FOCUSABLE);
        par = new HorizontalFieldManager(Field.FIELD_HCENTER | Field.NON_FOCUSABLE);

        cat = new CategoriaFieldManager(i);
        eImage = EncodedImage.getEncodedImageResource("img/categoria" + i +".png");
        eImage = LoaderScreen.resize(eImage, (int) Display.getWidth() / 5, (int) Display.getHeight() / 5, true);
        cat.add(new BitmapField(eImage.getBitmap()));
        lf = new LabelField("Categoria " + i, Field.FIELD_HCENTER);
        lf.setFont(font);
        cat.add(lf);
        par.add(cat);

        cat = new CategoriaFieldManager(i + 2);
        eImage = EncodedImage.getEncodedImageResource("img/categoria" + (i + 2) +".png");
        eImage = LoaderScreen.resize(eImage, (int) Display.getWidth() / 5, (int) Display.getHeight() / 5, true);
        cat.add(new BitmapField(eImage.getBitmap()));
        lf = new LabelField("Categoria " + (i + 2), Field.FIELD_HCENTER);
        lf.setFont(font);
        cat.add(lf);
        par.add(cat);

        row.add(par);
        add(row);
        //add(cat);
    }

}
}
```

For the element inside the grid i extended a VerticalFieldManager and implemented the FieldChangeListener:

```
public class CategoriaFieldManager extends VerticalFieldManager implements FieldChangeListener{

private int colores [] = {Color.BLUE, Color.ALICEBLUE, Color.CHOCOLATE, Color.DARKORANGE, Color.YELLOW};
private int _idCategoria;

public CategoriaFieldManager(int idCategoria){
    super(Field.FOCUSABLE);
    _idCategoria = idCategoria;
    setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createSolidBackground(colores[0]));
    this.setPadding(new XYEdges(15,30,10,30));
    this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createSimpleBorder(new XYEdges(20,20,20,20), Border.STYLE_TRANSPARENT));
    //cat.setCookie(new Integer(i));
    this.setChangeListener(this);
}

protected void sublayout(int width, int height){
    super.sublayout((int) Display.getWidth() / 5 , (int) Display.getWidth() / 5);
    setExtent((int) Display.getWidth() / 5, (int) Display.getWidth() / 5);
}

protected void onFocus(int direction){
    setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createSolidBackground(colores[1]));
}

protected void onUnfocus(){
    setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createSolidBackground(colores[0]));
}

public boolean isFocusable(){
    return true;
}
protected boolean touchEvent( TouchEvent message )    {
    int x = message.getX( 1 );        
    int y = message.getY( 1 );        
    if( x < 0 || y < 0 || x > getExtent().width || y > getExtent().height ) {
        // Outside the field            
        return false;       
    }        

    switch( message.getEvent() ) {                  
    case TouchEvent.UNCLICK:                
        fieldChangeNotify(0);               
        return true;        
    }        
    return super.touchEvent( message );    
}

   protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) {
      if (status != 0) {        // you did not have this check
         fieldChangeNotify(0);
      }
      return true;
   }
public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
    UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen( new ListadoEstablecimientosScreen(_idCategoria) );
    /*UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
            Dialog.alert("hola mundo");
        }           
    });*/
}

}
```

The problem that I've found is that when I touch the screen (anywhere) and then use the trackpad the phone freezes, I have to restart it to use it again. Then comes a notification that says the application was using too many resources. If it helps I've been testing in a BlackBerry Bold 9900

Comment: it says `[250456.19] Signal level only changed - ONS not updated`  and that the process is a CPU hog, but like I said, it only happens when I touch the screen and then use the trackpad

Comment: I don't think the problem you are seeing is caused by the code you have displayed, there is something more, for example something that is listening to the change events you are driving from the CategoriaFieldManager instance. But in this case can you remove the touchEvent handler from this code and then see what happens when you touch and then click.  or click and then click.